# Is it possible to retrieve imap emails from a copied outlook email account?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, imap

I need help!

I set up my Outlook email account to IMAP and am very happy with it. Except I copied the account to have access on my laptop as well. When I did that it sucked all of my emails onto my laptop (and sending the new ones there too). I want it back on the desktop but it is taking WAY to long emailing them back. I am afraid to delete any settings because I can't afford to loose any emails (old or new).

Can someone help me please? How do I transfer my emails back??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you did was:

1. created an IMAP account on your desktop and
2. created a **POP** account on your laptop (which then downloaded all your email)

You can do the following:

1. Back up your .PST file on the laptop (just to be safe - look under account settings, "data file" tab for the location of your .PST)
2. Delete your POP account on the laptop
3. Create an IMAP account on your laptop for the same email address and copy or move your emails from your local inbox folder back up to the IMAP folder, after which the emails will be visible from both machines via the IMAP account.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but this is my understanding of your issue:

‘The e-mails from your account have downloaded to your laptop and the accounts have different states of e-mails on each machine and you want to balance them without loosing the data totally?’

Comment: It sounds like one of them isn’t updating then, I have my iPhone and Outlook using the same account via IMAP and if one e-mail is deleted then it’ll sync almost immediately on the other device. Try refresh both devices and see.